# Add JUnits without running

Tags: eclipse, junit

How can I add a JUnit test to the JUnit test runner in eclipse without actually running/debugging it?

[image: JUnit test to add]

Answer (score 0):

How about this annotation:

http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Ignore.html

@Ignore

Comment: That's ok, but I'd have to add that annotation every time I wanted to add a test.

Comment: I think you can use the @Ignore on the entire class of tests.